# Android: a findViewById() method that returns values we don't need to cast

Tags: android, findviewbyid

As I'm tired of writing a cast operator for EVERY `Activity.findViewById()` that returns raw `View`, I finally tried [one way that was suggested by Internet](http://biginteger.blogspot.jp/2011/04/better-findviewbyid-that-doesnt-require.html).

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <T extends View> T findViewByID(int id) {
        return (T) this.findViewById(id);
    }
}
```

**Note** this isn't overloaded (the last "D" is upper case). The compiler says we can't cast `View` into `T`. Is there anything wrong with my implementing? Strangely, this suggestion was hardly seen in English websites (e.g. even in our lovely Stack Overflow), and the exception was the site posted above.

Comment: what is your JDK and android version?

Comment: Mine is Android 2.2 and JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine in my test project. No compiler error:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is your JDK and android version?

Comment: Was about to post the same thing - @Quv are you still using Activity.findViewById() elsewhere in your project? Perhaps use a more obvious method name to distinguish between the two...

Comment: JDK 1.6.0_30, Android Target API-16

Comment: Mine is Android 2.2 and JDK 1.6.

Comment: Just switched to API-8 (2.2), no problem either.

Comment: @seanhodges no, only within the `protected <T extends View> T findViewByID(int id) {}` block do I use Activity.findViewById(). @chruli umm...so strange.

Comment: @Quv have you tried a new empty Android project and test this code?

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to you I finally figure out my incredibly silly mistake. I made "my own" `View` class in my project).

Comment: You must be using Android API 26

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this approach adds some subtle complexity overhead for the next Android maintainer (who would be used to the casting approach) to save a few characters in the code files.

I would propose to cast the Views in the traditional way, or opt for a reflection-based solution like [Roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample?tm=6).

Comment: thanks. There is only one person behind my small project and the maintainer is me, but your introduction seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a custom eclipse-builder that generates classes with references for each layout-file, because:

- It's typesafe and easy to use
- RoboGuice and all other reflection-based APIs are very slow on Android.

In my opinion this is the cleanest and most performant way of solving this problem.

See my gist here for the builder: https://gist.github.com/fab1an/10533872

**Layout: test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350px"
        android:layout_below="@id/text2"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px" />

</merge>
```

**usage: TestView.java**

```
public final class TestView extends RelativeLayout {

    //~ Constructors ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private final ViewRef_test v;

    public TestView(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test, this, true);
        this.v = ViewRef_test.create(this);

        this.v.text1.setText();
        this.v.scroll.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**generated file (in `gen/`): ViewRef_test.java**

```
package org.somecompany.somepackage;

import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.lang.String;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public final class ViewRef_test {

    public final TextView text1;
    public final TextView text2;
    public final ScrollView scroll;


    private ViewRef_test(View root) {
        this.text1 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        this.text2 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        this.scroll = (ScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    }

    public static ViewRef_test create(View root) {
        return new ViewRef_test(root);
    }


}
```