# findViewById dynamic cast in func?

Tags: java, android

I would like to make a function that automaticly cast my **findViewById-View-from reference**.
Can i achive this somehow?

```
private View getReferenceForView(View view, int resId)
      {
         view =  (view.getClass())findViewById(resId);


          return view;
      }
```

**view.getClass() is not accepted there, but i would like to achive something like this in call:**

```
myView = getReferenceForView(myView, R.drawable.someresid);
```

So i can get reference for my views without the annyoing casting part.

Comment: check if (view instanceof textview) for example

Comment: I need a dynamic function, so i need to get the Classtype of the object

Comment: yup write a switch case like as above for textview ,button etc and then typecast accordingly

Comment: Please see my answer here for an easy and performant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23030620/342947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to use the approach you want is to use reflections `instanceof`. But this leads in a huge if-else block for every available View in Android.

You would have something like the following:

```
private View getReferenceForView(View view, int resId)
{
     if(view instanceof TextView)
         view = view.findViewById(resId);

     else if(view instanceof EditText)

     // and so on..

     return view;
  }
```

I don't know your exact approach but I think this isn't worth the effort.

Comment: phew, its so sad :( Thanks anyway. I guess i wont write it then.